# Regex capture group that precedes or follows another capture group

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create a capture group that could precede or follow another capture group.

Given:

```
TAKE 4 MG BY MOUTH
INHALE 14 PUFFS
4 PUFFS INHALE
```

Wanted:

```
qty unit  rte
--- ----  ---
4   MG    BY MOUTH
14  PUFFS INHALE
4   PUFFS INHALE
```

My attempt, `(?:(?'qty'\d+)\s(?'unit'(PUFFS|MG))).*(?'rte'(BY MOUTH|INHALE))`, works only when the `rte` follows the `qty`/`unit` group.  What is this concept called?  A "look-around"?

Example: https://regex101.com/r/IRTYgU/1

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
^(?=.*(?'rte'BY MOUTH|INHALE)).*\b(?'qty'\d+)\s(?'unit'PUFFS|MG)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qb5kcP/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*(?'rte'BY MOUTH|INHALE))` - after any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible, there must be either `BY MOUTH` or `INHALE` (Group "rte")
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `\b` - a word boundary (to match the digits as a full number)
- `(?'qty'\d+)` - Group "qty": one or more digits
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(?'unit'PUFFS|MG)` - Group "unit": `PUFFS` or `MG`

Answer (score 3):

You may use this regex with a lookahead that contains a capture group:

```bash
^(?=.*\b(?'rte'BY MOUTH|INHALE))(?:\w+\s+)?(?'qty'\d+)\s+(?'unit'PUFFS|MG)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IRTYgU/3)

**Breakdown:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?=.*\b(?'rte'BY MOUTH|INHALE))`: Lookahead to make sure that line contains `BY MOUTH` or `INHALE` somewhere after start and we also capture this in capture group `rte`.
- `(?:\w+\s+)?`: Optionally match a word followed by 1+ whitespaces
- `(?'qty'\d+)`: Capture group `qty` to match 1+ digits
- `\s+`: match 1+ whitespaces
- `(?'unit'PUFFS|MG)`: Capture group `unit` to match `PUFFS` or `MG`